# How to know if an android app is developed on Android Studio or App Inventor?

Tags: android-studio, app-inventor

How to find out whether an android app is developed using Android Studio or App Inventor ??

Comment: Why do you think, there should be a difference in the payment? Why did you not define your requirements including price and programming environment to use in advance? If an app is doing what you requested, then the programming environment should not be relevant imho...

Comment: Ya but I just want to if it is possible to determine whether App Inventor or Android Studio was used to make the app.

Answer (score 0):

The apps if created by App Inventor and published on the play store contains a link or a credit for App Inventor. 
If the apps are created using Android Studio, there won't be such a credit for third party app development software.

Also as far as on development, a majority of android apps created using Android Studio are professional in look and use, while App Inventor is often used by novice or those who are trying to learn the basics.

I hope this helps.

Comment: There are [methods to hide that credit for App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/about.php), there are also methods to [disable the hardware menu button](http://baasapps.com/app-inventor/disabling-the-hardware-menu-button-mit-ai2/). Also there are [methods to have a more professional look](http://baasapps.com/app-inventor/theme-material-app-inventor-2/). There are also methods to modify the package name...Also there are other distributions of App Inventor available, for example http://thunkable.com or http://appybuilder.com...

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside of app, press the Android menu button.
2. About this app
3. Here you go! Some apps might have commented the credit with `<!--`, but still, the existence of this menu should tell you the truth.

Comment: as already said in the other answer:  There are methods to hide that credit for App Inventor, there are also methods to [disable the hardware menu button](http://baasapps.com/app-inventor/disabling-the-hardware-menu-button-mit-ai2/), so this is no 100% solution....